# What happened to search on Stackoverflow, words clearly used in posts are not found

Tags: bug, search

Apologies if this was asked before, but it's kinda hard to search for the word "search".

I wanted to search for posts showing examples of `ITestFilterService`, which I knew existed through Google. However, much to my surprise, when I search, it doesn't find any question.

Example of a question with that text in it: [NUnit Engine in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155573/nunit-engine-in-asp-net) (and there are [at least four of them)](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20ITestFilterService&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20ITestFilterService).

Comment: @Braiam, yes, that's probably a duplicate. It doesn't look like it got much attention from the SO team, though, which is unfortunate as many people rely on searching (and yes, it is a complicated task and as the commenter there said, the workaround is to use Google with `site:stackoverflow.com`, cumbersome but doable). I'll close this one.

Comment: Meh, I never need the site:stackoverflow.com. Stack Overflow is so popular that the top search results always contain good stack overflow results.

Comment: @gimsby usually that's correct. Except when it isn't ;), like in the example given.

Comment: Well that'd be no wonder as Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for code examples :) Google search results are quite contextually driven, just the fact that a particular class exists in a code listing is probably not enough to make a search result relevant enough to appear high in search results (or at all). The class you're looking for is part of a particular larger entity (library, framework, standard SDK) and it helps to solve a particular problem; searching for the larger entity and the problem being solved probably nets you more results.

Comment: @gimby good points. Though in this case I started wide and then narrowed down. But there simply isn't information anywhere, so either way, it would've yielded zero useful results. Hence my attempt to track down code samples on git and other places.